# Use of function in VB6 report label

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I'm trying to convert Number to words in a VB6 Report by using a function "SpellIndian".. how to use Function stored in module with VB6 Data Report Label?..Any Help is appreciated

```
report.Sections(5).Controls.Item("label22").Caption = SpellIndian(Format(rs.Fields("Amount"), "0.00"))
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: What is the actual problem? How is it going wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
report.Sections("Section2").Controls("Label2").Caption = SpellIndian(val(rs!Amount & ""))
```

refer [Convert Amount in Words](http://www.esjay.org/2020/02/22/convert-amount-in-words-in-vb6/)

Comment: How is it different?

Comment: I do not know what parameter type they are using with the spellindian function and why they have used the format function, Therefore I have also mentioned a link from which anyone can use the code to convert the Amount into Words. Which indeed is perfectly working.

Comment: @gserg - I believe that what's being done here is that appending an empty string to the recordset field will 'convert' a db null to an empty string, then passing that to `Val` will return a zero instead of any non-numeric data in the recordset field.

Comment: @MarkL `format(null, "0.00")`, which the OP had, also returns an empty string.

Comment: @gserg, correct on `Format` handling a null.  But `Val(null)` will throw an exception of "Invalid use of null", while `Val(null & "")` will return a zero.  Which is what the accepted answer post has.

Comment: It is as simple as it appears, The purpose to use (& "") is to remove null and return an blank string instead. Though my methodology is correct still someone has given a negative vote! Thank you!

Comment: @MarkL The OP had `SpellIndian(string)`, here it's also `SpellIndian(string)`. Both the OP's code and this code will handle `null` by converting it to an empty string. Hence the question, how is this answer different to what the OP already posted.

Comment: @MarkL Another issue is that this code is wrong when run on a locale that uses anything other than the `.` for the decimal dot. `Val()` always expects the string to be in en-us locale and use `.` for the decimal dot, but the `& ""` will implicitly apply `CStr()` to the number which will format it with the current locale's decimal dot. So on a computer where the decimal dot is e.g. a comma (`,`), `Val(42.2 & "")` will return `42`, not `42.2`, because it will pass the formatted string `"42,2"` to `Val` and it will truncate it at the `,`.

Comment: @gserg, The original question stated that the error was "type mismatch" (since been edited out), presumably occurring in the `SpellIndian` routine due to a non-numeric field from the db (maybe a null, maybe not). This code, while it is deficient in the ways you point out about locale and formatting, "resolves" that type mismatch by always passing in a numeric (or convert-able numeric). It'll convert a non-numeric (including null) to a zero value, while the original code will pass in the non-numeric (null being converted to an empty string). FWIW, it's not the way I would have handled it.